# How to correctly resolve path aliases in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am making a TypeScript application using Node.js 18.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  type: "module",
  types: "./@types/index.d.ts",
  exports: "./dist/main.js"
}
```

I am using `type: "module"`, so that I can use `import`/`export` syntax.

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@tools/*": ["src/tools/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "declarationDir": "./@types",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["./@types", "node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

This is my folder structure:

```
src/
├── tools/
│   └── log.ts
└── main.ts
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

This is my `main.ts` file, which is the entry point to my program:

```
import log from '@tools/log.js'
log("hello world")
```

and this is my `log.ts` file:

```
export default function log(message: string){
  console.log(message)
}
```

Now, in my console, I want to run:

```bash
$ npx tsc
# SUCCESS !
$ node ./dist/main.js
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@tools/log.js' imported from ~/dist/main.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am having so much trouble just starting my project, I'm confused regarding the three x, y, z pathways in TypeScript which breaks everything in any project:

1. `package.json` `"type"` field.
2. `tsconfig.json` `module`.
3. `tsconfig.json` `moduleResolution`.

These three can have multiple options, we have no idea which one is the best, and they always conflict with each another.

For instance, now I am using `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`, I can't use `ts-node`.

If I changed the `"module"` property, I can't use [`chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk).

And now, since TypeScript does not resolve the path aliases during the build, I'm having so much trouble setting up `tsconfig-paths` and I have no idea how to configure Babel or Webpack just for this simple task.

I was thinking about the simplest build workflow:

1. Write the TypeScript code, consuming path aliases feature.
2. Build your code using `tsc`.
3. Use some tool, like Babel for example, to resolve the path aliases in the `dist/` directory.
4. Run your code using `node ./dist/main.js`

This is the simplest build workflow I can think about.

But now I also have the development workflow as well, I have to *somehow* integrate the following to work together

1. `nodemon` or `node -w`, or `ts-node` (which is not working since `"type": "module"` in `package.json`).
2. `tsc -w`.
3. Babel.

Comment: The point of `compilerOptions.paths` is to let the compiler understand that _something else_ is going to ensure that those resolve. If you don't actually have anything doing that, don't tell the compiler you do (and use normal relative imports instead, `import log from './tools/log.js';`). More here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths.

Answer (score 4):

***Here's how to get your aliased paths to work with TypeScript.***

First, configure `paths` in `tsconfig.json` so TypeScript doesn't put squiggly lines on aliased paths like this:

```
import log from "@tools/log";
```

> Notice that the extension, like `.js` or `.ts`, should not be in the
> import path because the extension will change after doing a build.

Next, install these packages: `ts-node` and `tsconfig-paths`

```
> npm install --save-dev ts-node
> npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

The package `ts-node` helps the workflow because it runs TypeScript files directly like this:

```
> ts-node src/main.ts
```

Unfortunately, `ts-node` doesn't automatically work with aliased paths. It needs `tsconfig-paths` to resolve them. To use `tsconfig-paths`, add `ts-node` to `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {...},
  "exclude": [...],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Notice above that `ts-node` is on the same level as `compilerOptions` and `exclude`. Now `ts-node` can run files with aliased paths. Also, other packages that use `ts-node`, such as `nodemon`, can run TypeScript files like this:

```
> nodemon src/main.ts
```

***Here's how to get your aliased paths to resolve during a TypeScript build.***

You'll need these packages: `typescript-transform-paths` and `ts-patch`.

```
> npm install --save-dev typescript-transform-paths
> npm install --save-dev ts-patch
```

During a build, `typescript-transform-paths` resolves aliased paths into relative paths like this:

```
import log from "../tools/log";
```

To use `typescript-transform-paths`, add `plugins` to `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "plugins": [{ "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }] 
  }
}
```

Notice above that `plugins` is within `compilerOptions`. Now use `tspc` instead of `tsc` to build like this:

```
> tspc
```

The compiler `tspc` comes from `ts-patch` and allows TypeScript to use `plugins` during build. Now you can run the build file like this:

```
> node dist/main.js
```

> Note, this strategy will not work if `"type": "module"` is in
> `package.json`, so you may want to delete this line:
>
> ```
> "type": "module"
> ```
>
> You may also want to use `NodeNext` in `tsconfig.json` like this:
>
> ```
> "module": "NodeNext",
> "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
> ```
>
> For more information, I wrote an [article](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/rolazarcoding_typescript-activity-7100135096095031296-OIUz/) about TypeScript aliased
> paths in my [LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/in/rolazarcoding/), but you must be logged into LinkedIn
> to view it.

Comment: Since all my code is built with es modules. I have to use `type: module`.

Comment: I don't plan to use commonjs `require()` syntax again

Comment: Because you're coding in TypeScript, you can use `import` even without `"type": "module"`

Comment: Yes, however, the output of typescript will be in es modules `import/export` syntax. Which means, in order to run the `node` command on the `./dist` folder, you have to tell nodejs that you're using es modules using `type: module`.

Comment: The output of typescript is `import/export` because you're using `EsNext` in tsconfig.json in the `module` property.

Comment: To my understanding, you want to use `import/export` syntax and aliased paths in your `.ts` files, and you want to use `node` or `nodemon` to run `.js` files in the `dist` folder. The answer I provided above allows that. Does it not work for you?